# How can I customise the language of the JSON response in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n

I have a controller that has a mobile client. The response is currently in English; however, I'm questioning if there is a way to customise the language of the response.

For example:

> English: {   "success": false,   "message": "Error with your login or
> password" }

> Spanish:{   "success": false,   "message": "Error con tu usuario o
> contraseña" }

And, of course, the content of the "message" is going to be located in the language configuration file that Rails has, as follows.

> en.yml

or

> es.yml

The following is the function from where the response is generated.

```
def invalid_login_attempt
    warden.custom_failure!
    render :json => { :success => false, :message=> "Error with your login or password" }, :status => 401
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `I18n.t`?

```
render :json => { :success => false, :message=> I18n.t('your_key') }, :status => 401
```

Based on certain criteria, you can set the locale for every request in the `ApplicationController`; for example:

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = request.headers["X-Lang"] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

Comment: So in the request i have to set the language inside the header, in that way the api can translate the message?

Comment: As @claasz suggested, read the Rails's guide for internationalization https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: Im on my way to the documentation, btw... the solution that you gave works perfectly :)

Comment: but if you have no `X-Lang` header you always end up with the default locale. Anyway, this is the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting up internationalization (I18n) for Rails should be pretty much the same for HTML and JSON responses. Have a look at the [official tutorial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).